# What does シャレオツ mean?

Tags: translation

Full context: シャレオツだた

Google translate shows: I was Shareotsu.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[シャレオツ](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A3%E3%83%AC%E3%82%AA%E3%83%84) (syareotu) is slang for [お洒落](http://kotobank.jp/word/%E5%BE%A1%E6%B4%92%E8%90%BD?dic=daijirin&oid=DJR_osyare_-010) (osyare) .

Comment: What is the オツ?

Comment: @Tim It's the same thing as パイオツ from おっぱい. お洒落 is exaggerated as オッシャレ, then the characters are re-arranged, as well as small ッ becoming large.

Comment: Thank you - sorry if this seems obvious but if the ツ becomes large then can I confirm it is pronounced "tsu"?

Comment: @Tim Yes, that is correct :)

Answer (score 1):

しゃれおつ or シャレオツ means cool, fashionable.  Above.

Another version:  おつしゃれ is a rearrangement of the same word however this version tends to be used amongst media piers, show biz etc.  This version is not grammatically correct but still spoken as such.