# What is the etymology of パイセン?

Tags: etymology, slang, dialects

As a slang term for [先輩]{せんぱい}, パイセン doesn't seem to be very popular. I occasionally hear it used among young people. Is it mostly a term used in Tokyo (dialectal)? Where did it come from? My impression is that this term has been around so long that it is unlikely Internet slang.

Comment: ok. then that kanji read as senpai. and your katakana is saying paisen. thats why i suggested. here is my find :https://matome.naver.jp/odai/2142185449328216601

Comment: @アニケン, ハワイ(Hawaii)→ワイハ　みたいなやつじゃないですかね‥‥ グラサンとかパイオツ（（　**Edit** あ、これこれ→　https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%80%92%E8%AA%9E

Comment: @Chocolate はじめて聞きましたのでちょっとびっくり！
例文はたくさんあります。知らないことの勉強になりましてありがとうございました。

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/62941/7810

Comment: Sounds like a similar thing to French' verlen (I think that's how it's spelled) where they reverse parts of the word for *reasons*.

Comment: @ratchetfreak The correct spelling is verlan https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verlan :)

Comment: @Chocolate, 以下にちゃんとしたお答えを投稿してはいかがですか。^_^

Answer (score 1):

As Japanese can be written vertical too, Paisen results in reading the kanji from below to above. It is an internet slang popularized by comedy artists [Yano and Yano](https://matome.naver.jp/odai/2142185449328216601).

Comment: Where did you find that it is Internet slang?

Comment: Just word of mouth, through my office colleagues.