# Reversing the syllables of a word

Tags: word-choice

I have heard words like パイセン instead of 先輩. Is this commonly used? Is this applicable to all words or only certain words? Some other examples: しくよろ instead of よろしく

Comment: Highly related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/73167/what-is-the-etymology-of-%e3%83%91%e3%82%a4%e3%82%bb%e3%83%b3

Answer (score 1):

I take the liberty to comment on this even though I am not going to say anything related to Japanese...

In French, there is a similar way of talking that is called "Verlan", in which you invert syllables to confuse people (well originally, mostly to confuse and not be understood by the police). In spoken language, it dates back to the 50s and it is quite widely used nowadays, in everyday words, by people who are roughly aged below 40-50.

It is so very interesting to know that it also exists in Japan ! :) Thank you for sharing !

Comment: Hi Lena,  thank you for your input.  You don't have enough reputation to post comments to questions, but you can gain the reputation through answering questions.  Unfortunately, this comment was posted in the section for answers.  Since this is not an answer to the question, we will unfortunately have to remove this post eventually.

Answer (score 0):

Young (from my perspective, I am 40+) do that a lot (in "written", like chat, less often spoken). Often used as responses, when a 1-word answer works. Not applicable to all words. (And I have not heard of "しくよろ") (yes, not using much of the よろしく either)