# When did 「ヤッホー」 become a popular greeting?

Tags: etymology, greetings, casual, informal

The etymology of the very casual greeting 「ヤッホー」 appears disputed and undecided. Various theories and hypotheses have been suggested. This [site](http://www.worldfolksong.com/calendar/japan/echo-mountain.html) lists German, Hebrew, and 山伏 as possible sources. A lot of places claim it was a mountain climbing term ([this](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080720233045AAiorgu), [this](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%83%A4%E3%83%83%E3%83%9B%E3%83%BC/), and many others). My question is when did it become popularized among young people as a fashionable greeting? When did become a thing in Japan? Where did it start? Did it start among members of a subculture (e.g. various teen subcultures in 渋谷/原宿)? I know the term has been around for at least 10, 15 years.

Comment: Could you explain what made you think ヤッホー is a fashionable greeting that may be related to 渋谷/原宿 subcultures? Did you hear it used in an anime, for example?

Comment: I hear it used pretty frequently among my friends as a really casual greeting. Usually pronounced やっほ though.

Comment: @naruto I've heard it IRL... Admittedly I hang out mostly with young demographics.

Comment: I googled `挨拶 ヤッホー` but found nothing related to "recent fashion"...some believe it's 昭和-ish and some believe it's simply odd/rare. I think it's been used by a few speakers for decades, but it's never been "popular"... ([This](http://www.nicotto.jp/blog/detail?user_id=480953&aid=60808719) article was interesting)

Comment: @naruto That's indeed very interesting! 昭和? Didn't know this term was that old. I thought it was a recent fad. By "popular" I meant in relative terms, like not necessarily a lot of people use the term and it is known in some circles. When someone says to their friend 「ヤッホー」, their friend wouldn't go 「なにそれ？ギャグ？」. That kind of popularity.

Comment: [チョリーッス](http://zokugo-dict.com/17ti/chori-su.htm)とかは recent fad と言えると思いますがヤッホーは遙かに古いです。ただ使う人が少ないだけで。まあ流石に「チャオ」や「アロハ」よりは relatively popular だと思いますが…。

Comment: I wonder if the use as a greeting might be related to slang coinage patterns based on sound swaps and reversals.  おはよう → drop the honorific = はよう → swap the consonant sounds = やほう → adding emphasis = やっほう. Possibly inspired by [倒語【とうご】](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/倒語), but taking things in a different direction.

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi Ah, reminds me of [my first ever post](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/73167/what-is-the-etymology-of-%e3%83%91%e3%82%a4%e3%82%bb%e3%83%b3) here.

Answer (score 2):

The word itself has been widely recognized for a long time as "something you shout in the mountains". Even [novels written in the 1950's have examples of ヤッホー](https://myokoym.net/aozorasearch/search?word=%E3%83%A4%E3%83%83%E3%83%9B%E3%83%BC).

In town, it may be used very occasionally as a humorous, unique greeting. Well, sometimes people feel おはよう is too uninteresting and want to say something different. I may have heard ヤッホー used in this way once or twice in the last 20 years. However I don't think it has ever been "popularized among young people as a fashionable greeting" in the 21st century. This is an old word everyone knows since childhood, and as far as I know, there is no reason for it to suddenly become a fashion. Theoretically, there may be a community (e.g., fans of a singer) where ヤッホー is used as a popular greeting, but I am not aware of such an example.

Answer (score 1):

No one says yahoo in Japan.
Some decades (around 100-70) ago, Yahoo was used for making echo or voice call someone in the distance at mountain site. Yahoo is recognized as a calling in laud voice for distance, so it may use for joking. Never used as a popular greeting.
Decent people do not yahoo for greeting.

Comment: Sorry to say, you have no idea what you are talking about. Thirty years in Japan - and it’s what my mother-in-law says every time we see her, as well as a number of my Japanese friends.