# Word used backwards モノホン?

Tags: nuances, form

The word モノホン is simply 本物 but inversed and in katakana. The definition in the dictionary is the same. Is it an exception or it's a common pattern to reverse like that? Does it add a certain nuance?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/62941/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/73167/9831